# How to fix: TypeError: e.wpcf7.parent.querySelector(...) is null for WordPress Contact form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

When I try to send a message through the Wordpress contact form I get this error in the console `TypeError: e.wpcf7.parent.querySelector(...) is null` and I can't find a solution specific to Wordpress and contact form 7, just custom forms. I'm using Wordpress version 5.7.1

Comment: Try implementing my answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200938/contactform7-shows-post-get-error-on-submission-wordpress-woocommerce-site/67210844#67210844

Comment: That has worked @Howard E, thank you very much

Comment: Feel free to upvote that answer since it helped you.